# My website title is not changing since two months

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress based site recently before 3 months I changed the title of my site [www.tbsolutionsll.com](http://www.tbsolutionsllc.com/)
But still it is showing me the old title, can you please look at this site and see if any code issue you find so tell me and elaborate me how can i fix it at my end. Please help me.

Comment: Try webmasters.stackexchange.com

Comment: <title>Medical Billing Services | Medical Billing Company &amp; Solutions</title>
That's the code so it's right, I don't think your code is updating but there I cant help you

Comment: one thing i missed to inform , old title was Total billing solutions and the new one i added Medical Billing Service but in the Google search engine index it is showing me the old one since more than 3 months.

Comment: Google caches this data, you could try asking them to crawl your site more in the code, do you have access to the code?

Comment: Yes I have cpanel access of this site, I am worried I am not much technical guy.

Answer (score 2):

In order to see the changes in Google results to reflect the recent changes to your website you can do 2 things:

(1) wait ( for days , for weeks or who knows may be months and years )

(2) This is somewhat complex ( for the first timers only ) procedure, it will request Google to refetch or reindex your website in order to reflect new changes.

all you need to do is to to Register your website to [Google Webmaster](https://www.google.com/intl/en/webmasters/) ( by proving your site ownership ) after that go to **settings => Crawl => Fetch as Google** even after that you have to wait but not more than a week.